# Is there a way of extracting portion of a key value between delimiters?

Tags: jq

Here is my JSON. Its in a file called `file1.txt`

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "bar": {
                "second": {
                    "key1": "some/path/to/delimiter1_FIRST_IMPORTANT_VALUE_delimter2",
                    "key2": "OK_as_it_is",
                    "key3": "Just to show there is more stuff"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "bar": {
                "second": {
                    "key1": "some/path/to/delimiter1_SECOND_IMPORTANT_VALUE_delimter2",
                    "key2": "Also_OK_as_it_is",
                    "key3": "Just to show there is more stuff"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is extract PORTION of the `key1` value - the bits between `delimiter1` and `delimiter2` which would be **_FIRST_IMPORTANT_VALUE_** and **_SECOND_IMPORTANT_VALUE_**

I know that the following ALMOST works:

```
$ cat file1.txt | jq '.foo[].bar.second | (.key1[23:46]),  .key2'
"_FIRST_IMPORTANT_VALUE_"
"OK_as_it_is"
"_SECOND_IMPORTANT_VALUE"
"Also_OK_as_it_is"
```

...but as you can see, it misses the last character of **_SECOND_IMPORTANT_VALUE_**

So I need a more generalised form of the `jq '.foo[].bar.second | (.key1[23:46]),  .key2'` that replaces the numbers `23` and `46` with values determined from **delimiter1** and **delimiter2**

I really want to keep it to a single line - without using bash variables over multiple lines, sort of keep it within **jq**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
.foo[].bar.second
| (.key1 | capture("delimiter1(?<v>.*)delimter2").v)
, .key2
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BOnbXIbskPN)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a regex:

```
cat file1.txt | jq '.foo[].bar.second | (.key1 | match("delimiter1([^*]*)delimter2").captures[0].string), .key2'
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this answer relies on the first and last characters of the extracted text being underscores.  In reality, what is needed is everything between **delimiter1** and **delimiter2** - which may include 0 or more underscores.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In this way would you meet the requirement you indicate?